# Power management issue or network connectivity

Tags: networking, power-management

I'd like to have your advice, folks. It's in my business environment and I am assigned to fix the issue.I have PC running Windows 10. It's on LAN but not in domain. Every night it should 'copy' a local file to shared remote file server. It works fine every day except Saturday i.e. it falls to copy to server because (likely) it fails to connect to share. I started to investigate and noticed in 'event viewer' that on Sunday morning at 9 AM it has Warning like: "Network link is disconnected"
I setup 'ping' batch every 15 sec and it confirms that on each Saturday from 11 AM till Sunday 9 AM it failed to ping and then it restores.
Than I setup a Scheduled Task to copy a file every 15 min to that 'share' assuming it might keep connection alive but it did not help. I mean that log also shows that it failed to copy at that time.
My questions: 
1. what could be the reason?
2. how could I fix it?
3. does it look like network adapter issue or rather 'power settings' issue (I checked that power setting is set to 'balanced' and 'standard' and in most cases action is 'never' sleep and etc
4. how else could I troubleshoot it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the shared remote file server stays up on Saturday?

Comment: You have scheduled backups running on weekends, don't you? (saturating all bandwidth)

Answer (score 0):

Folks,
It’s running daily because it copied backup file. Backup happens at 10 PM.  Remote server is always on and I decided that I will change the schedule to 10 AM because it looks as the valid slot. 
This is not a fix of the root but I hope it should work for me. 
Likely ticket could be closed. 
Thanks